# Set Update Time in Custom module on Grid

Tags: adminhtml, grid, magento1.9.2.3

I am Created one Custom Module called : **Sigmasolve/Recipe**.
But Problem is that on Grid Page only Display `Updated Time` Column But not Display any Data in That Column. And also in Database only create column like `updated_time` but not store any "data" in that Field.
I am Using Magento Version:1.9.2.3 .
Any Kind of help will  appreciated.

Comment: If only `update_time` column is empty than you may not have  set the value for that while saving data from your controller

Comment: but what can I put in save action for updated_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save `updated_time`  from your controller use this-

**if you want to save current time**

```
$yourModelCollection->setUpdatedTime(Varien_Date::now())->save();
```

**Or if you want to save any particular date then**

```
$yourModelCollection->setUpdatedTime('your_date')->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following function in your Sigmasolve/Recipe model file.

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    parent::beforeSave();
    $this->setUpdatedTime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:m:s'));
    return $this;
}
```